# Attempt at finding period in string with strpos not working

Tags: php, strpos, period, punctuation

I'm trying to find if there's a period in a string with strpos, but for some reason it prints out "There's no period." every time I run the code. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```
$text = "Hello.";

if (strpos($text, "." !== false)) {
echo "There's a period.";
}
else {
echo "There's no period.";
}
```

**Expected result**

```
There's a period.
```

**Actual result**

```
There's no period.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parenthesis are not matching correctly.

With the way you have it right now, you are passing the result of `"." !== false` as the second argument to `strpos`.

Change

```
if (strpos($text, "." !== false)) {
```

to

```
if (strpos($text, ".") !== false) {
```